# Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $ while parsing JSONString from docx file

Tags: android, json, gson

I have JSONArray of several JSONObjects in a .docx file. I want to write its entries in the local database. For this, I am using Gson. I have used following code for this.

```
InputStream is = context.getAssets().open("myfile.docx");
    JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
    reader.setLenient(true);
    reader.beginArray();
    while (reader.hasNext()) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        try {
            MyItem item = gson.fromJson(reader, MyItem.class);
            getMyDao().create(item);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    reader.endArray();
    reader.close();
```

My file has the string like

```
[{"key1":"stringValue1","key2":"stringValue2,"key3":intValue1,"key4":"stringValue3"},...]
```

When I run the app I get **Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $**. I have gone through all related answers on StackOverflow but didn't help. Please help.

Comment: I bet that the contents of your `InputStream` aren't what you expect. The `.docx` file type is likely to include a lot of markup/metadata and I doubt that your stream is just the json. Try printing the contents of the stream to see what it contains.

Comment: I found the problem. Actually, my docx file was compressed. That's why the string was not as expected. I created txt file instead of docx file and problem was solved. @BenP. thanks for your reply.